# Call order of the React life cycle componentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle, react-lifecycle-hooks

I have some questions...
why do we have such sequences of the componentWillUnmount? **from parent to its children.**

is it possible to reverse and bubble it? **from children to their parent?**

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-ntbji?file=/index.js)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Man extends React.PureComponent {
  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    console.log("Man");
  };

  render = () => "Man";
}
class Hello extends React.Component {
  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    console.log("Hello");
  };

  render() {
    return <p>Hello {this.props.children}</p>;
  }
}
class Root extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    visible: true
  };

  render = () => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button
        onClick={() => this.setState(({ visible }) => ({ visible: !visible }))}
      >
        Click
      </button>

      {this.state.visible && (
        <Hello>
          <Man />
        </Hello>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById("container"));
```